# Include .Net framework installer in the Wix Installer

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I am building a Wix installer via code.

```
var bootstrapper =
new Bundle("Cochlear Baha Fitting Software 5.4", chain)
{
     IconFile = @"icon.ico",
     Version = new Version(FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(4, 5, 2),
     UpgradeCode = new Guid(Guid.New(),
     Application = new ManagedBootstrapperApplication("%this%"),
     PreserveTempFiles = true,
     Manufacturer = "",
     OutFileName = $"installer.exe",
     SuppressWixMbaPrereqVars = true
 };
```

I've added this the NetFx46Redist to the Chain too;

```
 var chain = new ChainItem[]
 {
     new PackageGroupRef("NetFx462Redist"),
 }
```

So, as I know that I should include the Dot Net framework to my installer. But I don't know how? Could you help me?

Comment: Are you following [this guide](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html)? It uses XML rather than the API route but the patterns/concepts should be mappable.

Comment: Yes! But the question is that how I can add Payload group to the bundle from the code. Because I create the wsx file from the code.